# How to downgrade mercurial?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using mercurial version 5.3.1. For some reasons, I want to downgrade to mercurial 4.6.2. Is there any convenient way to do that?

machine description:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

How do I install mercurial?
sudo apt-get install mercurial

I need specifically need version 4.6.2

Comment: Get that version and install it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Which version of Ubuntu do you use? How did you install mercurial? A package from the default package sources? Do you specifically need version 4.6.2 or would a different 4.x.y version also be OK? Can you explain your "some reasons" why you want to downgrade?